# Regex with SED command

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I have a unique problem. Or at least I've found it to be unique based on my searches.
I am trying to bulk rename files in bash using sed initially to match a file name string, then use that string to rename it.

I am having issues doing so and was wondering if someone could point me in the correct direction, i'm willing to learn but not yet a regex ninja.

I know I can use SED to match the string like this:
sed -E 'regexhere'

I also know I need to escape some characters in order for it to work in bash.

So far I have this but it doesnt work either - something to do with unterminated regex.

```
([S,E]{1}([0-9]{2})+)
```

I believe my regex needs to match the pattern of finding `S` or `E` upper or lower case followed by two digits...then concatenate that with `A-Za-z0-9` prior to that pattern.
Or if the title has 4 digits in a set of braces, i.e. a year and all text preceeding that, again concatenated.

Then it should be a matter of replacing dots or spaces with underscores.

Sample input strings:

```
File 1: Name.of.show.S10E99 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
File 2: Name of show S09E99 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
File 3: Name of show S10E01 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
File 4: Name of movie (2020) sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
File 5: Name of movie (2021) sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
File 6: Name of show s11 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
```

Expected output strings

```
File 1: Name_of_show_S10E99
File 2: Name_of_show_S09E99
File 3: Name_of_show_S10E01
File 4: Name_of_movie_(2020)
File 5: Name_of_movie_(2021)
File 6: Name_of_show_s11
```

Any help much appreciated.
J

Comment: If you want to do bulk renames, why not use the `rename` command?

Comment: I have looked into this but it still requires regex as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes but you can use the more powerful PCRE.

Comment: `sed -e 's/ [^ ]*$//' -e 'y/ ./__/' file`. I assume `File x: `s are not parts of the strings.

Comment: Why do you have `,` in `[S,E]`? If you only want to match `S` or `E` use `[SE]`.

Comment: Just to be clear: `([S,E]{1}([0-9]{2})+)` matches an uppercase S _or a comma_ or an uppercase E (the `{1}` quantifier is redundant here), followed by one or more instances of two digits. A bracket expression is a _set_ of characters, you don't need to put a comma there unless you want to match a comma.

Comment: Is `File 1:` `File 2:` `File 3:` part of the input?

Answer (score 0):

I do not get your regex. I do not understand why do you match `E` and why do you match a `,`. I will propose mine. The following:

```
echo 'Name.of.show.S10E99 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
Name of show S09E99 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
Name of show S10E01 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
Name of movie (2020) sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
Name of movie (2021) sdf[sdfsdf](2222)
Name of show s11 sdf[sdfsdf](2222)' |
sed 's/[ \.]/_/g; s/\(\([Ss][0-9][0-9]\|([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\)[^_]*\).*/\1/'
```

Replace spaces and dot by `_` and then remove anything after `S` or `s` followed by two digits or `(` followed by 4 digits followed by `)`. The command outputs:

```
Name_of_show_S10E99
Name_of_show_S09E99
Name_of_show_S10E01
Name_of_movie_(2020)
Name_of_movie_(2021)
Name_of_show_s11
```

You can learn regex with fun with https://regexcrossword.com/ . Read sed manual and https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html . See `man 7 regex`. Remember that sed by default uses basic regular expression, you have written what seems to be an extended regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies here - I begun to abandon hope, turns out I have numerous naming conventions I want to rename which will involve multiple regex steps.

Further research found that I could use an application like filebot to achieve this.
Although I still want to get this resolved I think the most maintainable way would be to write in python in multiple steps then call python script from bash.

My regex I think should be something like [Ss][0-9]{2}[Ee][0-9]{2}
That would just capture some of the file details and is a newer way of writing regex as others have said.